# Installed programs not appearing at the Dash Home?

Tags: ubuntu

Some software that I install on my Ubuntu doesn't appear on the Dash Home menu.

For example, I installed Komodo Edit (thru a .sh file). If I want to run this program, I have to go to the directory where its located and then click on it. If I type Komodo on the dash home menu, it just won't appear.

Could it be it's because I didn't install it thru 'apt-get' (komodo is not available there)

How can I enable a program on the dash home menu?

Comment: A part of what packaging by the distribution does is to make sure the correct configuration files are placed, and that the whole mess works well together (for example, making your desktop environment aware of new programs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a `komodoedit.desktop` file and save it on `~/.local/share/applications/` and make it point to your executable file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Komodo Edit
Comment=Komodo and stuff
Exec=/path/to/the/execucable/file
Icon=/path/to/an/appropriate/icon
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Categories=Application;Utility;TextEditor;
MimeType=text/plain
```

Accomodate the values accordingly. You should now  be able to at least find it on the menu or search options.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Did just like you told me but only appeared after I restarted the pc, thanks!